# "AlarmReceiverChangeImage" error message in PendingIntent statement inside a method

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to set up a PendingIntent inside a PreferenceActivity in a method but Eclipse displays a red underline error "AlarmReceiverChangeImage cannot be resolved to a variable". The error is on "AlarmReceiverChangeImage" which is the name of a BroadcastReceiver.

Can you tell me how to change the code so it will not give the error on "AlarmReceiverChangeImage"?

```
private void setRepeatingAlarm(int time_before_changing_wallpaper) {

    /*
     * Set up alarm manager and get it going.
     */
    AlarmManager myAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(SettingsActivity.this, 0,
                    AlarmReceiverChangeImage, 0);

    myAlarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, START_TIME,
            time_before_changing_wallpaper, myIntent);
}
```

Update:
After looking at the link provided by Kurtis I also found it will work if I made the following changes to the code.

Added this static final:

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

```
protected static final Intent AlarmReceiverChangeImage = null;

SharedPreferences pref;
```

Changed the method to look like this:

```
private void setRepeatingAlarm(int time_before_changing_wallpaper, Intent AlarmReceiverChangeImage) {
```

Changed the call to the method to look like this:

```
                        /*
                         * Set the default wallpaper changing time of 10
                         * seconds if it has not already been set.
                         */
                        String str_list_time_before_changing_wallpaper = pref
                                .getString(
                                        "list_time_before_changing_wallpaper",
                                        "");

                        if (str_list_time_before_changing_wallpaper
                                .equals(null)) {

                            /*
                             * Set the repeating alarms.
                             */
                            setRepeatingAlarm(EVERY_10_SECONDS, AlarmReceiverChangeImage);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the documetnation for the [getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method. You'll notice the third argument is supposed to be an Intent, not a BroadcastReciever as you're trying to do. What you need to do is create and Intent and then put a IntentFilter on your BroadcastReciever in the manifest so that your BroadcastReciever receives the Intent when ever it's broadcast.

Comment: Hi Kurtis, Thanks for the help. Truly, Emad.